# how do I get the device ID for a specific network interface?

Tags: network-interface, ethernet

I have 2 similar dual-port NICs here. Both are made by Intel but one in branded HP and the other one is branded Intel. The vendor/device ID for both are different.

I can get the device ID using:

```
lspci -nn -vvv | grep Ethernet
```

BUT I do not know how to associate a particular device ID to a network interface. I know I can uninstall 1 card and let the other remain but still woulnd't help me when both cards are installed.

I've searched the net and I didn't see anything useful. Thanks

**example:**

```
eth2 belongs to 
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:10bc] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) [8086:000a]

eth3 belongs to
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:105e] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82571EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:000a]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 ethernet ports from 2 devices with the same vendor/device id. I can match the pci slot to the interface name by comparing the interrupt assignment.  I'm not sure you will be able to do this as you seem to have a multi-function device which might share an interrupt.

In my case:

```
$ lspci -s 03:00.0 -vv | grep Interrupt
     Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 31
$ lspci -s 05:00.0 -vv | grep Interrupt
     Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 32
```

And the matching interface p4p1 or p4p2 is found in the first and last columns of:

```
$ cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
 31:   47757902  108675810   PCI-MSI 1572864-edge      p4p1
 32:   25923809   86364594   PCI-MSI 2621440-edge      p4p2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user@host:~$ lshw -c network -businfo

Bus info          Device      Class      Description
====================================================
pci@0000:03:00.0  ens160      network    VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
pci@0000:0b:00.0  ens192      network    VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
pci@0000:13:00.0  ens224      network    VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed when trying to map the Proxmox PCI hardware UI to the pfSense setup UI. All I needed to do was do a `apt-get install lshw` since it wasn't installed by default.